# Создать гибкую HTML таблицу с помощью Python из данных Excel файл

Tags: html, python, excel

Данные которые храняться в Excel файле в следующем виде :

```
Date        ID  Name    var1    var2    var3    commit
2019-05-10  123 Abc       *      *        *      32szx
2019-05-06  123 Abc       *      *        *      32szx
2019-05-06  123 Abc       *      *        *      32szx
2019-05-06  123 Abc       *      *        *      32szx
2019-05-04  123 Abc       *      *        *      32szx
2019-05-03  123 Abc       *      *        *      32szx
2019-05-01  123 Abc       *      *        *      32szx
2019-05-10  123 Abc       *      *        *      32szx
2019-05-06  123 Abc       *      *        *      32szx
2019-05-06  123 Abc       *      *        *      32szx
2019-05-06  123 Abc       *      *        *      32szx
2019-05-04  123 Abc       *      *        *      32szx
2019-05-03  123 Abc       *      *        *      32szx
2019-05-01  123 Abc       *      *        *      32szx
```

Необходимо получить такую таблицу только в HTML с помощью Python.

Особенность заключается в том, что при данные меняются постоянно.
В примере данных выше, необходимо по условию отобрать строки за текущий день.

Данная HTML таблица будет вставляться в письмо и отправляться юзерам.

Подскажите, в какой тип данныхн нужно из ексель импортировать в питон ?
И как сделать автоматически изменяемый шаблон... спасибо за любую помощь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте модуль [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html):

```
import pandas as pd  #  pip install pandas

df = pd.read_excel(r'/path/to/file.xlsx', parse_dates=['Date'])
mask = df['Date'].dt.floor('D') == pd.to_datetime('today').floor('D')
df[mask].to_html(r'/path/to/file.html', index=False)
```

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">\n  <thead>\n    <tr style="text-align: right;">\n      <th>Date</th>\n      <th>ID</th>\n      <th>Name</th>\n      <th>var1</th>\n      <th>var2</th>\n      <th>var3</th>\n      <th>commit</th>\n    </tr>\n  </thead>\n  <tbody>\n    <tr>\n      <td>2019-05-06</td>\n      <td>123</td>\n      <td>Abc</td>\n      <td>*</td>\n      <td>*</td>\n      <td>*</td>\n      <td>32szx</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <td>2019-05-06</td>\n      <td>123</td>\n      <td>Abc</td>\n      <td>*</td>\n      <td>*</td>\n      <td>*</td>\n      <td>32szx</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <td>2019-05-06</td>\n      <td>123</td>\n      <td>Abc</td>\n      <td>*</td>\n      <td>*</td>\n      <td>*</td>\n      <td>32szx</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <td>2019-05-06</td>\n      <td>123</td>\n      <td>Abc</td>\n      <td>*</td>\n      <td>*</td>\n      <td>*</td>\n      <td>32szx</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <td>2019-05-06</td>\n      <td>123</td>\n      <td>Abc</td>\n      <td>*</td>\n      <td>*</td>\n      <td>*</td>\n      <td>32szx</td>\n    </tr>\n    <tr>\n      <td>2019-05-06</td>\n      <td>123</td>\n      <td>Abc</td>\n      <td>*</td>\n      <td>*</td>\n      <td>*</td>\n      <td>32szx</td>\n    </tr>\n  </tbody>\n</table>
```

Comment: простите, в екселе есть ещё данные. которые обрезаются с помощью питона. можно ли как то при импорте в html обризать их по определённому условии ? 
Например в данном случае по дате

Comment: @WilteRatenau, в Pandas все это делается достаточно просто. Приведите небольшой воспроизводимый пример данных (в таком виде, чтобы данные можно было скопировать) в вопросе и то что вы хотите получить н выходе. [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Исправил данные. В таком варианте подойдёт ?

Comment: А так же момент, что эта таблица должна быть вставлена в опредёленный кусок текста уже готово html

Comment: @WilteRatenau, по поводу `"эта таблица должна быть вставлена в опредёленный кусок текста уже готово html"` - это уже тех. задание для фриланса, а не вопрос для SO ;)

Comment: окей. не могу разобраться с индексом... не отберает строки по списку индексов